# Is a good practice to use a contract just to store ether?

Tags: contract-design, wallets

Is it a good practice to use a smart contract just as storage of eth with no functionality? Not even locking functionality, just having eth there?

Or in such a case a wallet is the correct practice?

Comment: I think more details are needed. While a plain wallet is probably more secure against attacks on the network, there are other threats to the store (or, more importantly, retrieval) of ether. For example, with long term storage, access to keys may be lost (e.g., forgotten password or bitrot) or ether is lost due to key-owner death. There are ways of addressing these issues with wallets. Contracts can also keep ether tied up intentionally (similar to time-locked vaults at banks). Thus, you need to elaborate on your question for a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to store it, use a wallet.
With a contract you expose those ETH to unnecessary risks.